# Upload callback in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to configure CKEditor to allow the user to upload an image from her computer. I'm using filebrowserUploadUrl, so I can upload the image to the server and get back the URL assigned to it, but I can't figure out how to pass the URL to the actual editor...

Some examples on the net talk about returning from the server something like `<script>parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction ...`, but I think it's quite ugly, isn't there a way to tell CKEditor "after the image is uploaded, call this function'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read again the syntax: you get the CKEDITOR object and tell it to call back a function, so it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, sorry, what I meant is: is there a way to setup the callback from the client side (javascript) instead of having the server return the javascript call itself?

Comment: No, that would be more complex than the current API.

Answer (score 2):

The server shouldn't return javascript for the client to render.

Even though the following is an ugly ugly... ugly hack.. I still prefer it over sending javascript from the server:

(Example of automatically inserting the image in the editor once the image is uploaded - works with 4.4.7)

```
var onUploadImage = function (dialog) {

    // Get the contents in the iframe
    var iframe = $('.cke_dialog_ui_input_file iframe');
    iframe.one('load', function(ev) {
        var fileUrl = ev.target.contentDocument.body.innerText;
        dialog.getContentElement('info', 'txtUrl').setValue(fileUrl);
        $(".cke_dialog_ui_button_ok span").click();
    });
};

var onLoadImageDialog = function () {
    var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent(); 

    // Open default tab
    this.selectPage('Upload');

    $('.cke_dialog_ui_fileButton').click(onUploadImage.bind(null, dialog));
};

var onDialogDefinition = function( ev ) {
    var name = ev.data.name;
    var definition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( name !== 'image' ) {
        return;
    }
    definition.onLoad = onLoadImageDialog
};

CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', onDialogDefinition);
```

Of course, the right way would be to create a custom plugin.